# Chromecast start another web service upon chromecast button push?

Tags: chromecast

Just a simple question...

```
  I haven't dived into the chromecast docs yet
  but can someone lend some knowledge, that's probably
  already out there.

  When a chromecast icon is pressed within an application is there anyway
  either from thirdparty apps or my own, have muliple http requests executed
  so that the chromecast is activated and some other process is started via
  web services aswell?
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as the developer of the sender application you can do anything you want once the user interacts with the button.  The button is part of your app, so sending messages to a web service is allowable.

Please review the documentation: https://developers.google.com/cast/developing_a_sender for further details on how everything works.

Comment: thanks for push in the right direction. I see now that chromecast is just another thing to interface with inside an activity/application. A very physical in your face thing but just another "thing" to communicate with inside the code. thanks!